# Cron Job and script file

Tags: scripts, cron

I am very much new to this OS, but learning fast.

I follow instructions from below link and everything is done accrodingly

https://www.dynu.com/DynamicDNS/IPUpdateClient/RaspberryPi-Dynamic-DNS

cron job runs on given time I can verify if by seeing system logs but it do anything. But when I run the command

```sh
echo url="https://api.dynu.com/nic/update?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD" | curl -k -o ~/dynudns/dynu.log -K -
```

on command prompt I get a result and information is updated on dynu.com website. This means that script is not running (If I am not wrong).
I tried this on 18.04 and on raspberry pi 3 model B. Any body can help?

Comment: Do you use any environment variables in your script? I'm not sure if tilde expansion is supposed to work in crontab, try absolute paths instead (both in crontab and in your script). Does the script work when executed on command line?

Comment: Why you use `curl -k`, the certificate of that website is valid ... That is pretty unsecure, especially considering you sending the password o0 Also, why do you use `echo "url=..." | curl -K -` and not just `curl "..."`

Comment: @danzel yes, script works when I executed on command line

Comment: @pLumo I have no  idea why use curl -k, the string is provided by dynu.com. I also wrote to their support and they replied that everything is fine when script executed from command line or by using a browser but do nothing when run by crontab.

Comment: When cron fails, there is output. Look up how to redirect cron output to a file so you can read the error message. Note that a cron job is NOT executed in your environment (it's executed in cron's environment), so testing on a terminal is not a reliable indicator of success.

Comment: @user535733 cron output in both cases goes to dynu.log file and there is nothing. but when executed by command line or run by browser the output stores in dynu.log file and it confirms that script runs successfully.

Comment: Does that mean YOU changed the cron job redirection (`>/dev/null 2>&1`) to something else? Because the instructions you linked to direct you to discard the very output you need instead of logging it.

Comment: @user535733 I am sorry I did not changed anything but there is output when executed by command line or run by browser.

Comment: Th output you need is being discarded, not logged. Only script output is being logged, not cron output. Go back to my first comment for what I recommend you do about it.

Comment: @user535733 I am sorry but I am not sure about this, will appreciate if you help how to log the output

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with exactly the same description as yours (tutorials for dynu and duckdns are the same).

For me it helped to change from

```
*/5 * * * * /home/pi/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

to

```
4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59 * * * * /home/pi/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Both ways I was able to see the program run

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ service cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-01-02 21:27:11 GMT; 9min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 285 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 881)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─285 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Jan 02 21:27:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Jan 02 21:27:12 raspberrypi cron[285]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 02 21:27:12 raspberrypi cron[285]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jan 02 21:29:01 raspberrypi CRON[557]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jan 02 21:29:01 raspberrypi CRON[558]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 02 21:29:03 raspberrypi CRON[557]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi
Jan 02 21:34:01 raspberrypi CRON[613]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jan 02 21:34:01 raspberrypi CRON[614]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 02 21:34:02 raspberrypi CRON[613]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi
```

But only by specifying the minutes for the program to run, it actually updated ip address on duckdns site. Tested and rebooted raspberry multiple times, always the same result.

Hope this helps.